# Jasmine Framework for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, karma-runner

We are creating a test framework for a Angular Web API Project. I have researched about Testing frameworks like Jasime, Mocha etc.

My question is, do we need a test runner like karma along with Jasime/Mocha to run & test test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, karma will be the test engine that will run your jasmine tests. Jasmine is a test API / framework, karma is a test engine that will spawn javascript environments able to run your tests.

Comment: ok does it mean we can run tests without having some test runner like karma?..do we have any way for looking at code coverage kind of things

Comment: You can probably run tests without a test runner, but test runners like Karma just makes everything so much simpler.  Karma also provides test coverage with a plugin called `karma-coverage`.  My company uses something called Sonar, but I just use `karma-coverage` for all of my personal projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your tests just straight in an HTML page, but it's easier to just use karma. You need to use something like Karma if you're going to test directives, because you need the html2Js preprocessing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can you install these from Nuget packages or do we need to do it any other way for an angular project?

Comment: http://codeforcoffee.org/setting-up-angular-js-jasmine-and-karma-in-visual-studio/ I personally just run karma from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for the link.It details all the steps. It does not use Nuget it uses npm

Comment: Let's start doing our own searches if we don't like what someone else has provided. Your question doesn't ask anything about nugget.